# MYSQL check difference between dates and update table acordingly

Tags: mysql

I want to apply update to a table row through mysql prepared statement based on time difference between column `installed` and actual time `DATEDIFF`.

Here is my update and insert statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `installs` (
`idinstalls` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`key` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`DateTime` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`channelpref` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`contractorid` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`additiona` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`mail` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`installed` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`version` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`process` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idinstalls`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `installs` VALUES (1,'1478997547716','Test instalation 1','2016-12-05 10:47:21',NULL,NULL,'Test',NULL,'2016-11-13 01:39:07',NULL,''),(2,'1478997633546','Tomo','2017-01-24 16:05:10',NULL,NULL,'Test',NULL,'2016-11-13 01:40:33',NULL,''),(3,'1479003293243','Test instalation 2','2017-01-24 04:26:49',NULL,NULL,'Test',NULL,'2016-11-13 03:14:53',NULL,''),(4,'1479118582052','Beta','2016-11-21 19:40:10',NULL,NULL,'Test','','2016-11-14 11:16:22',NULL,''),(5,'1479124220728','Beta 2','2017-01-22 15:54:41',NULL,NULL,'Test','','2016-11-14 12:50:20',NULL,''),(14,'1480154887591','','2016-11-26 12:41:01',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'2016-11-26 11:08:07',NULL,''),(17,'1483456759196','','2017-01-13 11:42:06',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'2017-01-03 16:19:20',NULL,''),(18,'1484474379679','','2017-01-24 12:12:41',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'2017-01-15 10:59:41',NULL,'')
```

The columns that are relevant to this question are: `key`,`name`,`installed` and `process`.

Query should update column process based on these requisites:

If column `name` has a input (it is not null nor empty field) column `process` should be assigned value '1'.
If column `name` does not have input, query should check difference between 2 dates, first one is date and time that is in column `installed` for that row and other is actual current date and time, if datetime difference is greater than 30 days it should update column `process` for that row to a value '0'.

This is my [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c898ab/1)

Comment: The fiddle's great, but other than that I feel we've regressed somewhat.

Comment: Seems key is not relevant here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the datatype timestamp for columns DateTime and installed. Then you may do the following.

```
update installs set process = '1' where name is not null and name != '';
update installs set process = '0' where (name is null or name = '') and datediff(now(), installed) > 30;
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer was helpfull, i will continue working on it and modify it to fit my needs. +

Comment: actually you can keep the table structure and the query statements should still work.

Answer (score 0):

If I was asking the question, I'd formulate the data set this way, and construct my question accordingly...

```
CREATE TABLE `installs` (
  `idinstalls` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `key` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `installed` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idinstalls`)
);

INSERT INTO `installs` VALUES 
( 1,'16','Test instalation 1','2016-11-13 01:39:07'),
( 2,'46','Tomo'              ,'2016-11-13 01:40:33'),
( 3,'43','Test instalation 2','2016-11-13 03:14:53'),
( 4,'52','Beta'              ,'2016-11-14 11:16:22'),
( 5,'28','Beta 2'            ,'2016-11-14 12:50:20'),
(14,'91',''                  ,'2016-11-26 11:08:07'),
(17,'96',''                  ,'2017-01-03 16:19:20'),
(18,'79',''                  ,'2017-01-15 10:59:41');
```